# How do I do a git show in Atlassian SourceTree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

How do I do the equivalent of a

```
git show <hash>
```

in Atlassian's SourceTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to Log View (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>).
- Click on a branch under 'Branches' in the left panel.
- Click on a commit in the log view in the main panel (on the right).
- You can view all changes introduced by the commit in the bottom panel.